# Input multiple data into SQL column

Tags: sql

I Plan to create a database that consists of these attributes

1. id
2. name
3. job
4. work_schedule

For example, I want to input Mike the Janitor, and he works every Wednesday, Thursday and Sunday. How do I input this into SQL effectively ? I've tried to use array (For example work_schedule = [3,4,7]). But, is there anything method that is easier ?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: **Do not** store multiple values into a single column! That's a horribly bad design and practice, and it violates even the **first normal form** of database design! If you have multiple items to store for an entity - add a separate table with a 1:n relationship - that's the relational way of doing things!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use bitwise operation.

use this values constant

```
Monday  = 1
Tuesday = 2
Wednesday = 4
Thursday = 8
Friday = 16
Saturday = 32
Sunday  = 64
```

Then workschedule for 3, 5, 7 will be

```
SET workschedule = 4 + 16 + 64;
```

And select to get jobs on Wednesday  will be

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE workschedule  & 4  > 0
```

Comment: Is better to use  
Use bitwise operation.

use this values constant

Monday  = 1
Tuesday = 2
Wednesday = 4
Thursday = 8
Friday = 16
Saturday = 32
Sunday  = 64
Then workschedule for 3, 5, 7 will be

SET workschedule = 4 + 16 + 64;
And select to get jobs on Wednesday will be

```SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE workschedule  & <FlagValue> = <FlagValue>```

Comment: Non-atomic data. Why? Or let's go futher and store as XML/JSON column.

Comment: @lad2025 Not sure about your comment, do you mean is something obscure?, For something so simple I thing works ok.

Comment: @lad2025 is really an atomic value, a bit flag is stored as a simply number that not differs from save another number in other column, both are data, the meaning of that data (known as information) is a task of the programmer or the system itself.

Comment: @KellermanRivero No, maybe number is one value but I need to do some operation (bitwise in this case) to get to real value. I don't think it is atomic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :). Much appreciate it. Never thought of this method. I will try bitwise operation in this case first. If I still get error, I will try flag.

Comment: This answer highly depends on the database.  For instance, Oracle uses `bitand()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an interesting question.  There are a handful of methods.  I can readily think of three, any of which might be appropriate given the circumstances.

- Have a separate table `WorkSchedule` for each possible combination of days when someone could work.
- Have a separate table of `WorkerDays` that has a separate row for each worker and each day when s/he could work.
- Store the information in one row.

The middle one is the most "SQL-like" in the sense that it is normalized, and should be flexible for most needs.

The third alternative seems to be the path you are going down.  A typical method is to store a separate flag for each day:  `MondayFlag`, `TuesdayFlag`, etc.

An alternative method is to store the flags within a single column, using bit-masks to identify the information you want.  Of course, this depends on the bit-fiddling capabilities of the database you are working with.

The actual choice of how to model the data depends on how it will be used.  You need to think about the types of questions that will be asked about work days.

Comment: Thanks for the method lists :). Much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using **Relational** Databases, so don't use:

```
 work_schedule = [3,4,7]
```

Database normalization: **[`1 Normal Form`](http://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/first-normal-form-1nf.php)**:

> A database is in first normal form if it satisfies the following
>   conditions:
>
> - **Contains only atomic values**
> - There are no repeating groups
>
> **An atomic value is a value that cannot be divided.**

Do not store multiple values in one column, unless you want to ask in future how to split CSV data and why it is so slow.

One way to go is multiple flags for every day:

```
id
name
job
is_working_Monday
is_working_Tuesday
is_working_Wednesday
...
```

Comment: More efficient is to save the work_scheduled as a bit flags.

Comment: Downvoter should explain why. I dont think that is bad answer. For smaller field set can work, But for longer options any of Gordon suggestion are needed for maintainable

Comment: Thanks for the answer :). Much appreciate it