# What's the good practice in SQL when I have to deal with a list of values in a column?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm new to SQL and I'd like to know how I could code the information of a many values into a single column. More precisely, suppose I have this table:

```
create table recurrent_events(
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    weekday integer,
    action text
);
```

For some records, the `weekday` column will have to contain more than 1 day (ex: Monday, Friday).

Is there a good way of doing this without using a list of values?

I thought of using flags to store the information of the days in the column `weekday`:

- `2^0` : Monday
- `2^1` : Tuesday
- ...
- `2^6`: Sunday

Adding the powers of 2 corresponding to the days and extracting the bits with the bitwise `AND`.

Is it a good choice? Are there alternatives or better techniques I should know?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input multiple data into SQL column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33317971/input-multiple-data-into-sql-column)

Comment: The bit map technique is a trick which will save you some speed and space (+1) but will cost you a little in terms of maintainability because the bitmap structure will need external explanation (perhaps naming the field `weekday_bitmap` will make it easier). The way I would handle it is to have another separate table which will store `(id integer, weekday integer)` data and may have multiple `weekday` entries for each `id`.

Comment: First, tag your question with the database you are using.  Second, explain how the data will be used.  The best data representation typically depends on how the data is being used as well as on what it represents.

Comment: "*I could code the information of a many values into a single column*" don't do this - **especially** if you are new to relational databases (and SQL) It violates all rules of normalization and should only be considered as a last resort if queries on your billion row table don't perform as you need them to.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've just tagged the question with the database. I want to use this table to store recurrent events. Each action (ex: Work out on Monday and Friday) will be inserted into another table containing all the events (recurrent and isolated) with the correct dates ((1, "Work out", "2015-11-09"), (2, "Work out", "2015-11-13")). The goal is to generate a timetable for the week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your table will not grow endlessly and understanding the contents of the columns intuitivly is more important than saving some memory/harddisk space or milliseconds to query the result:

I would create one bit/boolean column per weekday: **Mo Tu We... Su**

This is better than a join table to "tbl_weekdays" since you had to ensure then that nobody assigns the same weekday twice to the same event.

The bit coded solution you mention is very elegant from a technical POV, but requires implicit knowledge regarding the meaning of the bits. Separate columns make this knowledge explicit and ease SQL queries.

BTW: This solution only works because of the low cardinality of the distinct values (only 7) otherwise the number of columns would explode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think that's what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Your table structure suggests MySQL (the "autoincrement").

MySQL has a construct called sets, which may be what you are looking for (the documentation is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html)).  The elements of the set itself behave like `enum`s and are stored using bits.

In general, I have major reservations about using sets and enums:

- They are database-specific, so the code is less portable to other systems.
- There are hard limits on the sizes of the sets.
- They support arcane coding that can be hard to read and maintain (`WHERE set_col & 1`).
- The definitions of seemingly similar sets might vary from table to table.

The "normal" SQL method of storing this type of information is a junction table.  In your case, this would be one row for each action and weekday.  A set of boolean column, or even a string representation of the days of the week might also be appropriate, depending on how the information is being used.